# Is it possible to update Carbon Fields using update_post_meta

Tags: php, wordpress, carbon-fields

I have a plugin that uses the Carbon Fields SDK and in another plugin I would like to update that field without requiring the Carbon Library.

Is it possible, or are there any pitfalls, to simply doing something like:

```
update_user_meta($id, '_carbon_field_name', 'meta value');
```

or does one have to use the native carbon functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work:

```
update_user_meta($id, '_carbon_meta_key', 'meta value');
```